# Network adapter Disabled on windows azure virtual machine (how to reactivate)

Tags: windows, azure, networking, virtual-machine

I have a problem with my azure virtual machine (name : Davzen, resource group : Rs1). I made a bad manipulation accidentally : I desactivated the network adapter of the virtual machine , it has ejected me of the Remote Desktop and I didn’t manage to reconnect me since this moment. I tried : restart , réinitialise connection, change virtual machine plan ( 3,5go ram-> 7 go ram). But this setting persist and I didn’t manage to reactivite the network adapter and to connect me with Remote Desktop.
Can everybody help me ?

But it doesn’t work any at all

Comment: How did you disable network interface card?
If you disable IP forwarding, refer the following article to enable the IP forwarding:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-network-interface#enable-or-disable-ip-forwarding

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After you disable your NIC, you will not connect to your VM, we can follow those steps to enable it:

1.Go to the [Azure portal](https://ms.portal.azure.com/).
2.Select the affected Virtual Machine.
3.Select **Network Interfaces**.
4.Select the Network Interface associated with your machine
5.Select **IP configurations**.
6.Select the IP.
7.If the **Private IP assignment** is not **Static**, change it to **Static**.
8.Change the **IP address** to **another IP address** that is available in the Subnet, for example, change `10.0.0.4` to `10.0.0.5`.
9.The virtual machine will restart to initialize the new NIC to the system.
10.Try to RDP to your machine. If successful, you can change the Private IP address back to the original if you would like. Otherwise, you can keep it.

After you can remote desktop to the machine, you must **delete the old NICs** to avoid the potential problem:

1.Open **Device Manager**.
2.Select **View** > **Show hidden devices**.
3.Select **Network Adapters**.
4.Check for the adapters named as "Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter".
5.You might see an unavailable adapter that is grayed out. Right-click the adapter and then select Uninstall.
[image]
6.Now all unavailable adapter should be cleared out from your system.

More information about re-enable NIC from Azure VM, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/reset-network-interface).

Comment: It actually fixed my issue! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

if another ***azure VM*** is on same **Network security group** then it is quite easy. **And you do not want to lose Allocated Public IP assigned to this lost machine**.

1. Take lost Azure VM in **Stopped (deallocated)** status.
2. Add Extra NIC with in same **Network security group** and assign private IP Address only.
3. Start the machine.
4. Go other Azure VM running on same  **Network security group**. And Login it.
5. Inside this other Azure vm RDP the lost machine by entering assigned private IP Address for extra NIC.
6. Now **Enable** the disabled NIC of that lost VM.
7. Al last its time for normal RDP from out side and anywhere by its Public IP.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add network interfaces to an existing VM using the Azure portal. To add network interfaces to an existing VM, you must use the CLI or PowerShell.
If a network interface has a private IPv6 address assigned to it, it cannot be added to an existing virtual machine. You can only add a network interface with an assigned private IPv6 address to a virtual machine when you create a virtual machine. See [Network interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-network-interface-addresses) IP addresses to learn more about assigning IP addresses to network interfaces.
For reference you may go through these articles:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/multiple-nics?toc=%2fazure%2fvirtual-network%2ftoc.json#add-a-nic-to-a-vm

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/multiple-nics?toc=%2fazure%2fvirtual-network%2ftoc.json#add-a-nic-to-an-existing-vm